# How to connect to Oracle from far Computer in LAN?

Tags: c#, oracle

I have Computer A (with IP =  10.20.30.40) which stores the Oracle Database.

Data Source = ORCL , User = sa , Password = sa

---

I have Computer B(IP =  10.20.30.44) and I want to connect Computer B to computer A.

How can I do that? What is the Connection string that I need ? Any suggestions

Comment: I really hope you haven't posted the real Usernames & Passwords to production systems in your post. Even if the IP Address is a private internal IP

Comment: Eoin, sa/sa is commonly used in oracle docs, along with scott/tiger.  It probably doesn't matter about the IP addresses, since a baddie that penetrates your internal network will know all your oracle hosts after a 2-3 minute port scan.

Answer (score 4):

What Oracle version do you use?

Usually it is made using direct editing tnsnames.ora file (default location for Oracle 10g client = C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora) or GUI tool -> Net Configuration assistant.

Example of connection alias from my tnsnames.ora file:

```
ORADB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.16.50.1)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = ora10gdb)
    )
  )
```

ORADB - alias name, you use it as a db name when you connecting to a database from your environment

HOST - is a server host name
PORT - is Oracle service port name (1521 is a default port)
SERVICE_NAME - is a oracle database instance service name (can be more than one database instance on same server behind same port)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a 10+ Oracle client on computer B, you can use the [EZCONNECT](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/EZCONNECT) feature, which does not require to edit the TNSNAMES.ORA file : `sa/sa@10.20.30.40/1521:ORCL`. For instance :

```
sqlplus sa/sa@10.20.30.40/1521:ORCL
```